# Bash word wrap: Make GNU's fold --spaces option ALWAYS break at spaces

Tags: bash, gnu, word-wrap, fold

The documentation at http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/fold-invocation.html#fold-invocation is clear:

```
‘--spaces’

Break at word boundaries: the line is broken after the last blank before the maximum line length. If the line contains no such blanks, the line is broken at the maximum line length as usual.
```

However this is undesirable in my scenario because it breaks links and paths in the text. I don't really mind that sometimes the length is exceeded.

Is there other, more powerful version of fold around? Or is there an alternative?

More info: this is my code, a simple function for pretty printing text and do some indentation

```
fold -s -w $(( $COLUMNS - 4 )) <<< "$1" | sed -e '2,$s/^/    /g'
```

Desired behavior:

```
COLUMNS=40
```

Input

```
this is a text with some quite short and manageble text but also with some loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong words so please dont split the ooooos
```

Output

```
this is a text with some quite short and 
    manageble text but also with some loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
    words so please dont split the ooooos
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Not a programming question; voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow. Maybe ask at [su]. There are utilities which are not `fold` which have different behavior; maybe look at `par` (if it still exists).